# The package linux-firmware-nonfree causes Debian to not see my monitors

Tags: debian, firmware

When I boot up after installing that package, my monitors don't work.

I know that I can still get to a tty and that the system is working because I can run 'eject cdrom' and I can play the bell noise, but I can't see anything.

I know that it's specifically this package because I reinstalled the OS, rebooted, and everything was fine. Then I installed linux-firmware-nonfree and rebooted, and now the monitors don't work.

Debian 9.1.0

Nvidia GTX 970

Comment: Is there any related in `dmesg` after reboot?

Answer (score 2):

Well, nvidia drivers aren't the top top ones I've faced.

The probable reason may be some incompatibility between your xorg and your (non-free, binary) nvidia drivers.

The first what I would do in your place: removing the linux-firmware-nonfree and reboot.

Second, you may think on a kernel upgrade (if you aren't on the latest version of your distro).

My third try would be to load a more recent nvidia driver package from their upstream package distribution: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa . These are for Ubuntu, but you will have a good chance to make them working also on Debian.

If your card is older, you may try an older nvidia driver release - nvidia likes to forget about their older cards.

[Here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22) you can find the Debian sources for proprietary nvidia packages.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up reinstalling the OS and installing the nvidia-driver package instead.

Comment: @sam Sad :-( I am sure at least one of them had worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the OS and instead of installing linux-firmware-nonfree I installed nvidia-driver. This fixed the issue.